# the type XmlDataProvider is not found in silverlight application childWindow

Tags: .net, xml, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

Hello and thanks in advance for the help. I am sorry if this question is an obvious answer, I have been googling and searching for an answer but to no avail. I would like to use an xml data source within my silverlight child window. I attempt to use the xaml declaration within the grid controls resources as follows:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="WatchListData"></XmlDataProvider>
</Grid.Resources>
```

in the hopes that I would be able to set the data source in the code behind. However, I get the error "The type XmlDataProvider is not found." Is there a namespace or include you need in order to use it? If so what would that be? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

XmlDataProvider is not supported in silverlight